# What is the difference between if [[ condition ]] and if condition

Tags: bash

1st script

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the process name" process_name

if pgrep -x $process_name < /dev/null
then
        echo "Process is running"
else
        echo "Process is not running"
fi
```

2nd script -Not working because of [[ ]]

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Enter the process name" process_name

if [[ pgrep -x $process_name < /dev/null ]]
then
        echo "Process is running"
else
        echo "Process is not running"
fi
```

what is an issue??

Explanation for above

Comment: `man bash` describes how `[[` should be used. It's for special conditions, not for running commands.

Comment: The 2nd will be a syntax error

Comment: It will typically have a test specifier flag and an argument to the flag, ie `[[ -e /tmp/nonexistantFile ]]` test if the name file (**e**)xists. Many other test flags exist. There is also `[ some test here ]` and just `if test your test here ; then` providing similar functionality and levels of backward compatibly. (**test** is the actual keyword you use after `if`).  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're not grasping [conditional statements in shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs).

`if` takes a list of program invocations, then a semicolon and `then [...]; fi` to branch:

```bash
# Prints 'ls succeeded'
if more --help; find --version; ls; then echo ls succeeded; fi
```

`[` and `[[` are **programs** in and of themselves. `[` is just syntactic sugar for `test`:

```bash
# Equivalent invocations:
[ -f foo.txt ]
[[ -f foo.txt ]]
test -f foo.txt
```

`test`/`[` is a built-in helper program for shell scripts to be able to do useful tests like string comparisons and file existence and type checks.

`[[` is named for the POSIX sh's `test`/`[`. It's a GNU Bash only construct that does basically the same thing as `test`/`[` but has upgraded features like regex support, glob pattern matching and more.

The arguments to `test/`/`[` and `[[` have [their own section in the Bash man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005b_005b). You can't just insert any arguments between `[[` and `]]` and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
help [[
```

you'll see the syntax:

> [[ expression ]]
> Execute conditional command.
>
> ```
> Returns a status of 0 or 1 depending on the evaluation of the conditional
> expression EXPRESSION.  Expressions are composed of the same primaries used
> by the `test' builtin.
> ```

You can also check `help test` to see the valid expressions.